# Prove that, for any positive integer n: $(a + b)^{n} \leq 2^{n-1}(a^{n}+b^{n})$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality, induction, tangent-line-method

Prove that, for any positive integer n:  $(a + b)^{n} \leq 2^{n-1}(a^{n}+b^{n}) $
I tried induction theorem,
when $n = 1$ it is obviously right. But, 
say $n=k$, 
It does not make sense since I cannot expand the $2^{k-1}$($a^{k}$+$b^{k}$).

And I also looked through this similar question but no help.

[Prove: $(a + b)^{n} \geq a^{n} + b^{n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1368/prove-a-bn-geq-an-bn)

Comment: An identical [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/696917/85660) was asked earlier.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The simpliest proof:

as $x\to x^n$ is convex,
$$
\left(\frac {x+y}2\right)^n \le
\frac {x^n+y^n}2
$$
Now multiply by $2^n$ and you are done.

Comment: Can you explain a little more? Our course do not cover things like the "convex". Do you mean increasing?

Comment: convex mean, in a context of a real valued differential function, mean that the derivative function is increasing. If this is the case, a theorem yields $a_i > 0 \ \&\ \sum a_i = 1 \Rightarrow f(\sum a_i  x_i) \le \sum a_i  f(x_i)$. For exemple, the absolute value is convex.

Comment: @SonicFancy: why did you unaccept?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, this is only true for positive $a$, $b$.

For the induction step: suppose $(a+b)^n \leq 2^{n-1}(a^n+b^n)$ for all $a,b>0$. Multiplying both sides of the inductive hypothesis by $a+b$ (here we use $a+b>0$), we find $(a+b)^{n+1} \leq 2^{n}(a^{n} + b^{n})(a+b)$. It remains to show that $(a^n+b^n)(a+b) \leq 2(a^{n+1}+b^{n+1})$. This is equivalent to $(a^n-b^n)(a-b) \geq 0$, which is true as $x \mapsto x^n$ is an increasing function.

This is the generalized mean inequality for two variables (comparing the arithmetic mean and the $n$-th power mean).

Comment: After multiplying a+b to the supposed part, is that should still be  $2^{n-1}$?

Comment: And should I consider that the basecase is n=1?

Answer (score 4):

$$(a+b)^n\leq 2^{n-1}(a^n+b^n)\Longleftrightarrow\left(\frac{a+b}2\right)^n\leq\frac{a^n+b^n}2\Longleftrightarrow\frac{a+b}2\leq\sqrt[n]\frac{a^n+b^n}2$$
Which is a special case of the [generalized mean inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean#Generalized_mean_inequality) if $a,b\geq0$ and $n\geq1$ (can even be real).

The full inequality gives you a nice generalized bound
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^k a_i\right)^n\leq k^{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^k a_i^n$$

Comment: This is a little bit hard for me to understand but still thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Also, the TL method helps.

Indeed, since our inequality is homogeneous, we can assume that $a+b=2$ and we need to prove that
$$a^n+b^n\geq2$$ or
$$(a^n-na+n-1)+(b^n-nb+n-1)\geq0,$$ which is true by AM-GM:
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^n-nb+n-1)\geq\sum_{cyc}\left(n\sqrt[n]{a^n\cdot1^{n-1}}-na\right)=0$$ and we are done!